# Postgres: Error adding Foreign Key

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add a FK to a table, but whenever I try to alter the table, I run into an error. These are the queries I'm using:

```
ALTER TABLE geofences ADD COLUMN role_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;



ALTER TABLE geofences ADD CONSTRAINT geofences_role_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES auth_roles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The first query, runs perfectly, but when I try to add a constraint I get this message:

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "geofences" violates foreign key constraint "geofences_role_id_fk"
>   DETAIL:  Key (role_id)=(0) is not present in table "auth_roles".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error simply means that there are row in contains rows that have values in the column `role_id` that are not present in the table `auth_roles`. You need to fix your data before you can add the foreign key

Comment: Read the error message. There is a row in `geofences` where `role_id` is 0, but there is no row in `auth_roles` where `id`is 0. This would violate the constraint, so it cannot be created.

Comment: Just remove `DEFAULT 0`  from column `geofences.role_id`. This error happens because table auth_roles don't have a row with id = 0.

Comment: Thanks michel, I had to remove this line: NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;